# Change owner and permissions on folder

Tags: command-line, vbscript, cacls

I have the below script, it works fine, but how do I set it to keep security settings and add additional 'person' to the security group...

...and can `cacls` change the 'owner' of the folder?

I tired `/e` to edit instead of replace but it doesn't like it for some reason ?

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strFolder    = "D:\test"

setPerms     = "%COMSPEC% /c echo Y| C:\windows\system32\cacls.exe """ & _
                strFolder & """ /G mydomain\myusername:F & pause" 'added pause to see what the outcome is

WshShell.run setPerms
```

Answer (score 16):

`CACLS` is deprecated, you can achieve what you want with the recommended `ICACLS`. You want something like:

```
icacls.exe d:\test /grant domain\username:F
```

To make an addition to permissions and:

```
icacls.exe d:\test /setowner domain\username
```

To set ownership. Other options of interest from `icacls /?`:

```
/T indicates that this operation is performed on all matching
    files/directories below the directories specified in the name.

/C indicates that this operation will continue on all file errors.
    Error messages will still be displayed.
```